# OnClick event inside an Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, scope

I've been browsing some of the other questions on this topic, but it seems they aren't directly related to my issue.

I'm currently creating a plug-in for OWA, which are executed within an iframe on the website.

I have a Home.html page, with an attached script, main.js, which loads in a partial page.
On the partial page I try to make an OnClick event that targets a function in main.js - but for some reason it won't work.

the *main.js* script is being instantiated by a few different scripts as follows.
*Home.js* instantiates loader, of a type contained in *Loader.js*.
*Loader.js* instantiates a main, from *Main.js*.

```
<td><a href="#" onclick="functionName();"><div id="OpenOpportunities"></div>Opportunities</a></td>
```

I'm not sure if I'm just missing something scoping-related, but when I tried debugging it in the browser console, the iframe got in the way.

How would I go about calling the function in the Onclick?
I've tried most things I can think of, but to no avail - I recently came to javascript from a C# background, so the scoping is different to say the least.

Thank you

Comment: It would be helpful if you can share your html and JS code as well!!

Comment: Try `parent.functionName()`

Comment: parent.functionName() certainly tries to do the right thing, but I'm afraid that's where the iframe comes into play - output in the console states that a frame with origin "x" tried to access a frame with origin "y" and was blocked.

Comment: It will not work if your iFrame contents are loaded from a different domain. See: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-Origin-Policy

Comment: I'm quite new to JS, but I don't see how it makes sense that a page within the iframe can't call a method within the iframe also.